# AWS CodeDeploy script does not exist during AfterInstall hook

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am having trouble with executing my install_dependencies.sh script in AfterInstall hook-

it seems like my deployment-archive from which CodeDeploy agent is trying to run the scripts from does not yet exists during the AfterInstall hook.

I am getting this error that causes my deployment to fail:

```
ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2643)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: 
InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - 
Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/432f58a2-27d7-46c0-8091-1625eb8733af/d-Q3DGM6LPU/deployment-archive/scripts/install_dependencies.sh - 
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in execute'...
```

---

my appspec.yml file looks like this:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/myApp
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

---

for accessing the deployment-archive folder after the failed deployment attempt, i do get files in their correct path (the same path that appeared in the Error log):

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-87 scripts]$ cd  /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/432f58a2-27d7-46c0-8091-1625eb8733af/d-Q3DGM6LPU/deployment-archive/scripts/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-87 scripts]$ ls -ln
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 261 Aug 21 13:33 install_dependecies.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 0 0  69 Aug 21 13:33 start_server.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 0 0  56 Aug 21 13:33 stop_server.sh
```

my EC2 instance os is-

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-87 ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-87 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-10-87 4.14.62-65.117.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 10 20:03:52 
UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have already checked for execution permissions, and the content of my script files is empty (with only "exit 0" statement) in order to help sandbox the problem.

as far as i've seen in all examples- the scripts folder is expected to be in my deployed package and not outside of my deployment.

my appspec.yml is in the root folder of my project, and so is my scripts folder.

- if I eliminate the AfterInstall/BeforeInstall hooks from my appspec- the problem does not occur.

What am i missing? why does these file are not accessible during the AfterInstall/BeforeInstall hooks?

please help,
thanks